# How I can create my own pow function using PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, function, math, logic

I want to create a function in which I put two values (value and its power - Example function: `multiply(3, 3)` result `27`). I have tried so far but failed, I have searched using Google but I have been unable to find any result because I don't know the name of this function.

What I want exactly:

3,3 => 3 x 3 x 3 = 27
4,4 => 4 x 4 x 4 x 4 = 256

What I tried:

```
function multiply($value,$power){
    for($x = 1; $x <= $value; $x++ ){
        return $c = $value * $power;
    }   
}
echo multiply(3,3);
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian for upadating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oopsika, couldn't have asked a more obvious question. Use the built-in function named **[pow](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)** (as in a lot of languages)

```
echo pow(3, 3);
```

**Edit**

Let's create our own function.

```
function raiseToPower($base,$exponent)
{
    // multiply the base to itself exponent number of times
    $result=1;
    for($i=1;$i<=$exponent;$i++)
    {
      $result = $result * $base;  
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hanky , But I want to create my own function.

Comment: Oook, see the edit. The mistake in your function is that you are multiplying the base with exponent, not with base itself.

Answer (score 9):

The answer has already been accepted, but I had to come here and say that all answers here use a bad algorithm. There are better ones. Including very simple ones, like [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) that reduces the complexity from O(power) to O(log(power)).

The idea is to square the base while dividing the exponent by 2. For example

```
3^8 = 9^4 = 81^2 = 6561
```

There is a special case when the exponent is odd. In this case, you must store a separate variable to represent this factor:

```
2^10 = 4^5 = 16^2 * 4 = 256 * 4 = 1024
```

PHP isn't one of my strong skills, but the final algorithm is as simple as:

```
function multiply($value, $power){
    $free = 1;
    while ($power > 1) {
        if ($power % 2 == 1)
            $free *= $value;
        $value *= $value;
        $power >>= 1; //integer divison by 2
    }
    return $value*$free;
}
echo multiply(3, 3) . "\n";
echo multiply(2, 10) . "\n";
echo multiply(3, 8) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function exponent($value,$power)
{
    $c=1; 
    for($x = 1; $x <= $power; $x++ )
    {
        $c = $value * $c;
    } 
return $c;    
}
```

Comment: you scared me @ayazkhane ... i just checked this and its working fine

Comment: @habibulhaq please consider renaming the function to something else. `multiply` would not mean what this function does, as you know it already and some casual reader might mistake it for that and think oh this code is incorrect. Plus when we have common convention names for such operations why give them the name of a different operation :)

Answer (score 2):

- If you have **PHP >= 5.6** you can use the ** operator

> $a ** $b  Exponentiation  Result of raising $a to the $b'th power.

```
echo 2 ** 3;
```

- If you have **PHP < 5.6** you can use pow:

> number pow ( number $base , number $exp )

```
echo pow(2, 3);
```

- Your own function is:

```
function multiply($value, $power) {

    $result = 1;

    for($x = 1; $x <= $power; $x++){
        $result *= $value;
    }   

    return $result;
}

echo multiply(3,3);
```

Read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php

Answer (score 1):

Just try to run this code I hope your problem will be solved.
If you defining any function then you have to call it return value.

```
<?php
    function multiply($value,$exp)
    {    $temp=1;
        if($exp==0)
            return $temp;
        else
        {
             for($i=1;$i<=$exp;$i++)
             $temp=$temp*$value;
             return $temp;
        }

    }

    echo multiply(5,6);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Enter number (will be mutiplied):".PHP_EOL;
$value = (int) readline("> ");
echo "Enter number for multiplier:".PHP_EOL;
$multiplier = (int) readline("> ");

function power(int $i, int $n):int {
$result =1;
    for ($int = 1; $int < $n; $int++){
        $result *= $i;
    }
    return $result;
}

echo power($value,$multiplier);
```